# How to insert a unicode character in MathType formula?

Tags: unicode, mathtype

I would like to use unicode character (say ० or अ) in a MathType formula. How can I do it? Insert Symbol doesn't list these characters under any font. Pasting the character produces a missing glyph (question mark in a diamond). This kind of thing should 'just work' in 2018, right?